# Как пройти html валидацию в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, валидация, html-validation

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Выводит такие теги:

```
<meta name='robots' content='index, follow, max-image-preview:large, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1' />
<meta name="description" content="........." class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<link rel="canonical" href="..........." class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<link rel="next" href=".........." class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU" class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<meta property="og:title" content="............" />
<meta property="og:description" content=".........." class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<meta property="og:url" content="........" class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content=".........." class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<meta property="og:image" content="........." class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="120" class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="120" class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />

<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="....." href="...." />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="...." href="...." />

<script type="text/javascript">....</script>
<style type="text/css">....</style>
```

Как удалить `/` в конце?

И как удалить `type="text/javascript"` и `type="text/css"` ?

В файле `functions.php` там ничего нет

Какой файл в системе за это отвечает?

Хотелось бы без этой фигни, типа такой функции `str_replace( '<br />', '<br>', $content );` а изначально сделать правильный вывод тегов

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat%3A100%2C200%2C300%2C400%2C500%2C600%2C700%2C800%2C900%2C100i%2C200i%2C300i%2C400i%2C500i%2C600i%2C700i%2C800i%2C900i|Oswald%3A100%2C200%2C300%2C400%2C500%2C600%2C700%2C800%2C900%2C100i%2C200i%2C300i%2C400i%2C500i%2C600i%2C700i%2C800i%2C900i|Roboto+Slab........
```

ошибка

```
Bad value for attribute href on element link: Illegal character in query: | is not allowed.
```

Comment: А зачем? Это ведь не является ошибкой. [Trailing slashes in void-element start tags do not mark the start tags as self-closing](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-in-void-element-start-tags-do-not-mark-the-start-tags-as-self-closing)

Comment: @Simon validator.w3.org пишет что это ошибки и нужно исправить

Comment: Он выводит сообщение с пометкой `Info`, а не `Error` или `Warning`. Ссылка которую я привел, взята оттуда. И там даже описаны `So, for example, the following are all acceptable reasons for using a trailing slash in a void-element start tag` с перечислением ниже.

Comment: В любом случае, Вы и не найдете ничего конкретно в functions.php, так как большинство из тех тегов которые Вы привели в пример, генерируются плагином Yoast SEO и мета теги и все остальное генерируется автоматически.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_head()` - это хук-событие, которое используют плагины и темы чтобы добавить свой код (стили/скрипты/мета-теги) в `<head>` - [Источник](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_head)

`add_action()` - прикрепляет указанную PHP-функцию на указанный хук. В данном случае на хук `wp_head()` - [Источник](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_action)

В коде это может выглядеть так:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    echo '<meta name="yandex-verification" content="XXX" />';
    echo '<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">';
});
```

Или так:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_yandex_and_favicon' );
function add_yandex_and_favicon() {
    ?>
    <meta name="yandex-verification" content="XXX" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">
    <?php
}
```

В Вашем случае, судя по `class="yoast-seo-meta-tag"`, эти строки в `<head>` добавляет плагин Yoast SEO, значит в файлах этого плагина и нужно искать использование конструкции `add_action( 'wp_head', function)`.

Лично я в таких случая ищу нужный кусок кода в командной строке с помощью утилиты `grep`. Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А знаете как решить такую ошибку? `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat%3A100%2C200%2C300%2C400%2C500%2C600%2C700%2C800%2C900%2C100i%2C200i%2C300i%2C400i%2C500i%2C600i%2C700i%2C800i%2C900i|Oswald%3A100%2C200%2C300%2C400%2C500%2C600%2C700%2C800%2C900%2C100i%2C200i%2C300i%2C400i%2C500i%2C600i%2C700i%2C800i%2C900i|Roboto+Slab........` ошибка `Bad value for attribute href on element link: Illegal character in query: | is not allowed.` я так понял нужно заменить символ `|` но на что его заменить?

Comment: Попробуйте символ `&` вместо `|`.

Comment: Нашел решение, там нужно на `%7C` заменить